# Simple circuit to detect ac power loss and use dc backup?

Tags: batteries, adapter, ac-dc, ups

I want to make a simple circuit like those used in commercial emergency lights.

I would have a "walmart" AC to DC  adapter powering say a DC light or two. I would like it so when the AC powering the adapter goes out the DC battery backup in the light goes on.

Is this at all possible without complicated circuits and components? I want to try and use what little parts I have.

Comment: If the consumer is DC-powered, then you would only need two diodes.

Comment: Can you open that box of parts again... you closed it so fast I could not tell what parts you have.....

Comment: @Trevor My bad. I was going to see whst components people suggested and than see if i had them. Im new to the electronics thing and arent sure What everything is and does.

Comment: @TurboJ I think i see whst your saying. How exavtly would i put them in the circuit thougj

Comment: If you want simple, use a relay. You can't get much simpler that that.

Answer (score 4):

Use a relay with an AC coil to enable the output from the wall wart (and disconnect the battery) then, when AC is lost, the relay switches in the battery with it's normally closed contact whilst simultaneously disconnecting the wall wart.

Make sure that the AC voltage rating for the relay coil is suitable for you local AC power.

Answer (score 4):

As Andy mentions, a relay is your simplest choice, though I think I'd do it on the DC side instead of worrying about messing with the AC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE28pq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>